# Want to create outline from Lato in InDesign, text gets different

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, text

I want to make my thesis in InDesign. But there is a limit on the word count. To get around this, people suggested to take some text and create outlines. But when I export my file, the outlined text is thinner than the the text that is not be outlined. I'm using the font Lato.

Someone here know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm studying IT & Media Design, the teacher don't want us to deliver our thesis in a word document. You can consider it cheating but the limit is on 7500 words, which is not enough for me to tell everything I want.

Comment: If I were an instructor.. and imposed a limit of 7500 words... and I saw outlined type to circumvent that restriction... F or best case.. unsatisfactory and rejected. But then, I'm not your instructor :) There's a *reason* the instructor has imposed limits.

Comment: I was misunderstanding this whole situation, thinking that InDesign was imposing the word limit :P

Comment: Your actually not reducing word count per see. Your just hiding the fact. Trim or leave something out. (thesises do get better by trimming)

Comment: Hi MvGorkum, welcome to GDSE! It would appear you have accidentally created multiple accounts. Stack Exchange does not support more than one account per user on a site. In case your accounts interact (upvoting your own posts, for example), they are liable to be deleted. Please go to our [help section](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and contact SE to have this issue fixed.

Comment: @Lucian I strongly disagree. The question is about the difference in font rendering for an outlined and a non-outlined font.

Comment: Please keep discussion in the comments on-topic. The question is about a difference in font rendering in InDesign. Whether this is cheating or not, is irrelevant to the design part of this question--which is the only part we are interested in.

Answer (score 4):

This really won't *solve* the issue.. but perhaps explain it....

Live type and vector art is *different* when rendered in a PDF. Live type contains things like hinting, which tells the postscript how to draw the glyphs. Outlined type is just vector data, there is no hinting. The PDF just doesn't render outlined type the same as live type.

More specifically, **screen rendering** is commonly affected. Acrobat has a tendency to show i, l, and I (lowercase L and Upper case i) as being thinner than other outlined type. You can sometimes correct the screen issue by ticking the `Enhance Thin Lines` option in the preferences (Page Display). However, this is a per-system adjustment. Meaning it will effect how the PDF looks on *your system* not anyone else's. Other systems would need to alter the same preference.

If the goal is to make outlined type look *exactly* like live type which is surrounding it, you're in for a chore in many cases. A better alternative is to strategically outline separate pieces of text, such as headlines, bullets, etc. So any variation *could* be interpreted as intentional. However, even still.. if you were to outline "This is live type" there is a chance the three i(s) and the l would look thinner than the other outlines.

But, as posted in my comment above, were I the instructor and saw outlined type to circumvent word restrictions, I would not have a favorable opinion of the piece. Chances are there are very valid reasons for the restriction. But then again... maybe your instructor won't care or even notice. Heck, some of my college instructors actually *gave* credit if you found creative methods for handling assignments no matter how wrong the answer/assignment was.

Additional Caveat.. it could be the font itself. Lato is a Google Font and as such primarily designed for screen display as a web font. There's a chance it's not well constructed for print output. It's a minimal chance. Nonetheless, the chance does exist. I personally have never used Lato so I can't say for certain. You'd want to be certain you are using the latest version for print purposes http://www.latofonts.com/